# Place a two-column picture under the author affiliation and above abstract

Tags: graphics, floats, titles, two-column

I've been searching through the similar questions but none has worked for me. Basically, I am writing a two column conference paper with a existing [template](https://code.google.com/p/sigchi-latex/), what I want very simple is to place a picture span across two column right under the author affiliation and above the abstract, I've tried to apply the `figure*` but no matter I place the code fragment the picture will got pushed down to the second page. This is what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


% Load basic packages
\usepackage{balance}  % to better equalize the last page
\usepackage{graphics} % for EPS, load graphicx instead
\usepackage{times}    % comment if you want LaTeX's default font
\usepackage{url}      % llt: nicely formatted URLs

% llt: Define a global style for URLs, rather that the default one
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{%
   \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\bf\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{leo}


% To make various LaTeX processors do the right thing with page size.
\def\pprw{8.5in}
\def\pprh{11in}
\special{papersize=\pprw,\pprh}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{\pprw}
\setlength{\paperheight}{\pprh}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\pprw}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\pprh}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={SIGCHI Conference Proceedings Format},
pdfauthor={LaTeX},
pdfkeywords={SIGCHI, proceedings, archival format},
bookmarksnumbered,
pdfstartview={FitH},
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
breaklinks=true,
}

% create a shortcut to typeset table headings
\newcommand\tabhead[1]{\small\textbf{#1}}


% End of preamble. Here it comes the document.
\begin{document}

\title{SIGCHI Conference Proceedings Format}

\numberofauthors{3}
\author{
  \alignauthor 1st Author Name\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Address}\\
    \email{e-mail address}\\
    \affaddr{Optional phone number}
  \alignauthor 2nd Author Name\\
    \affaddr{Affiliation}\\
    \affaddr{Address}\\
    \email{e-mail address}\\
    \affaddr{Optional phone number}    
}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[tp]

\includegraphics[width=1.5\columnwidth]{1}

\caption{With Caption Below, be sure to have a good resolution image
  (see item D within the preparation instructions).}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure*}



\begin{abstract}
In this paper we describe the formatting requirements for
SIGCHI Conference Proceedings, and this sample file
offers recommendations on writing for the worldwide
SIGCHI readership. Please review this document even if
you have submitted to SIGCHI conferences before, some
format details have changed relative to previous years.
\end{abstract}





\end{document}
```

Could anyone help? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for `figure*` in a two-column document. You're going to have to avoid this.

Anywhere *before* making a call to `\maketitle`, add the following (replacing `example-image` with your image, including the `\includegraphics` parameters):

```
\makeatletter
\let\@oldmaketitle\@maketitle% Store \@maketitle
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{\@oldmaketitle% Update \@maketitle to insert...
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4\baselineskip]
    {example-image}\bigskip}% ... an image
\makeatother
```

The above inserts an image as part of `\@maketitle` (at the end), which is set in `\twocolumn` mode as part of the title. Using the documentclass [`sigchi.cls`](https://code.google.com/p/sigchi-latex/), it displays the following output:

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to squeeze multiple pics in a row?

Comment: @user1935724: Yes: `\includegraphics[..]{...}\par\includegraphics[..]{...}\bigskip` The images will be very tight vertically. So you could add a `\medskip` after `\par`.

Comment: I meant horizontally placed pics. What changes should I make based on your suggestion. never mind I figured it out with \quad

Answer (score 2):

An example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{\LaTeX Title}

\author{First Author\\
Institution1\\
Institution1 address\\
{\tt\small firstauthor@i1.org}
}

\twocolumn[{
\maketitle
\begin{center}
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Test caption}
\end{center}
}]

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1] % Replace with your real text
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It would be better to add some text explaining what your answer does.   If you could make your code independent of non-standard packages (`cvpr` is not in the main distributions nor on the ctan archive) that would make the answer useful to more people.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have provided the simplest version with standard packages. @AndrewSwann