# How do I put a figure* before my abstract?

Tags: floats, abstract

I'm sadly not using double-column abstract, just single-column.  This is based on the sigchi document class: https://code.google.com/p/sigchi-latex/

The obvious thing:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}
\begin{document}
\title{My awesome paper}
\maketitle
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=7in]{figures/teaser.png}
\caption{Some stuff about the teaser}
\label{fig:teaser}
\end{figure*}
\begin{abstract}Talking some more.\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Does not seem to work.  What is the correct way to do this?

Note that [Place a two-column picture under the author affiliation and above abstract](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146803/place-a-two-column-picture-under-the-author-affiliation-and-above-abstract) is not exactly what I want: I need a caption for my figure, still.

So I've tried also

```
\documentclass{sigchi}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\title{My awesome paper}
\makeatletter
\let\@oldmaketitle\@maketitle% Store \@maketitle
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{\@oldmaketitle% Update \@maketitle to insert...
  \includegraphics[width=7in]
    {figures/teaser.png}\bigskip}% ... an image
\captionof{figure}{Some fun facts about my image.}
\label{fig:teaser}
\makeatother

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

So that my figure shows up, however my caption does not show up below it; just on the second page...?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  It would be helpful if you could make your code example executable by starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  This will give important elements of your document environment that may help to solve the problem.

Comment: If your class uses double column abstract then the easiest thing to do is put the `\includegraphics` _in_ the abstract (and use `\captionof` from capt-of package if you really need a caption there.

Comment: Ah, yes, compilable.  Sorry!  I'll fix in just a moment.  I'm sadly not using two-column abstract... just one column.

Comment: some document classes (the ams classes among them) willfully suppress figures from falling at the top of page 1.  i'm not familiar with `sigchi` and it doesn't seem to be at ctan, but it may have a similar feature.  (in the ams classes, the code is in the `\maketitle` expansion, and there is a comment to this effect that is visible in the `.cls` files.  and i've just checked the basic classes -- the prohibition is there too.)  the code is `\@topnum\z@`.

Comment: I see a couple things in that class that have topnum:

`\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\def\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\def\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\def\textfraction{.2}
\def\floatpagefraction{.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\def\dbltopfraction{.7}
\def\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}`

So what do I do with them to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there with the `\@maketitle` redefinition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

\usepackage{capt-of,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@maketitle\null{{\myfigure{}\par}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\newcommand\myfigure{%
\centering
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}%\includegraphics
\captionof{figure}{Some stuff about the teaser}
\label{fig:teaser}
}
\title{My awesome paper}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}Talking some more.\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually also discovered that the sigchi class defines a teaser environment:

`\documentclass{sigchi}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\title{My awesome paper}

\teaser{
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/teaser}                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    \caption{Caption here.}
    \label{fig:teaser}
}

\maketitle
\end{document}`

Comment: @Valkyrie so it does:-) essentially the same as here, but chooses to put it after the title rather than before. (I wasn't sure where you wanted it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so how do you place it after the title? I think it would be useful for some people.

Comment: @Jubei For placing the figure after the title, you can use `\apptocmd` instead of `\patchcmd`: `\apptocmd\@maketitle{{\myfigure{}\par}}{}{}`