# How to add a one-column figure with caption after title and before abstract in a two-column document?

Tags: floats, positioning, titles, acm

I'm trying to add a teaser (figure) after title and before the abstract section in a document with acm_proc_article-sp class but no luck!

Tried to use the following solution by David Carlisle, but don't know how to change the code to put figure after the title:

[How do I put a figure* before my abstract?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170156/how-do-i-put-a-figure-before-my-abstract)

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@maketitle\null{{\myfigure{}\par}}{}{}
\makeatother

 \begin{document}
 \newcommand\myfigure{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{teaser}
    \captionof{figure}{Some stuff about the teaser}
    \label{fig-teaser}
   }
\title{a title}
\maketitle

 \begin{abstract} 
  abstract
 \end{abstract}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}% http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/acm_proc_article-sp.cls/view
\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@maketitle\@author{\@author \\[\normalbaselineskip] \myfigure}{}{}
\newcommand\myfigure{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}} \\[\normalbaselineskip]
  \refstepcounter{figure}\normalfont\textbf{Figure~\thefigure: Some stuff about the teaser}
  \label{fig-teaser}
}
\makeatother

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract} 
abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You original patch of `\@maketitle` in [`acm_proc_article-sp`](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/acm_proc_article-sp.cls/view) inserts the figure (`\myfigure`) as a replacement for `\null`. This is too early, making the figure appear *above* the title. Instead, I've placed it as part of the `\@author` construction, and therefore comes *below* that (and above the abstract).

Since [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) is not suggested with this document class (see the `.log` for some warnings), I've manually set **Figure 1: <caption>** using the same construction techniques employed by the class.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
    \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
    \usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \title{a title}
    \begin{abstract}
    An abstract
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{teaserfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{This is a teaser}
        \label{fig:teaser}
    \end{teaserfigure}
    \maketitle
    \end{document}
```

It worked for me with SIGCONF, and ACMART class.